# Getting "Add assembly" error when loading my user-defined Function into SQL as a DLL

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlclr

I can't import my assembly into SQL. It keeps saying "(assembly) is referencing and you need to load this assembly with your DLL". I add the assembly in the Bin folder, and it ask another. I have added 15 assemblies, and come to the conclusion I must have coded something incorrect. I posted the code that is blocking the DLL from being uploaded too SQL. I changed the URL and what not. So not worried about that.

I have tried adding the assemblies, I commented out the code in sections to see which part is making the assembly error. I also commented out the part of the code that was making SQL throw an error when creating the assembly. I figured out, it loads the DLL without any of the webrequest/Json data code. I even tried changing the Using and adding some/taking away and references as well in the properties.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;


public static IEnumerable Briefs()
{
    Credentials RunCredentials = GetCredentials();
    var client = new WebClient();
    var values = new NameValueCollection();
    values["UID_"] = RunCredentials.UserName.ToString();
    values["PWD_"] = RunCredentials.UserPwd.ToString();
    values["QUERY_"] = "Hlts";
    values["COLUMN_NAME_FORMAT_"] = "DATABASE";
    values["NO_LINE_BREAKS_"] = "N";



    string webAddr = "MyURL";
    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(webAddr);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/Json";

    using (var streamWriter = new 
StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
        {
            USER_ID = RunCredentials.UserName.ToString(),
            PASSWORD = RunCredentials.UserPwd.ToString(),
            Query_ID = "Hlts",
            complexParameters = new
            {
                type = "group",
                logicalOperator = "AND",
                children = new[] {
                  new { type = "filter",  name = "Original", 
                      comparisonOperator = "=",
                      value1 = "Car", value2 = "" }
                                            }
            }
        });

        streamWriter.Write(json);
    }

    var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    using (var streamReader = new 
StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        dynamic ProposalList = new 
JavaScriptSerializer().DeserializeObject(responseText);

        foreach (Dictionary<string, object> drow in ProposalList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(drow.ElementAt(3).Value);
            yield return drow;
        }

    }
```

My end game is to be able to create the DLL, and then create an assembly from the DLL in SQL without getting a error while keeping the Webrequest code in or changing it only slightly.

Comment: I assume you are talking about creating a CLR function?

Comment: You need to post the assemblies you've added and the actual assembly it is still complaining about.

Comment: SQL Server only supports some of the .NET libraries see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/clr-integration/database-objects/supported-net-framework-libraries?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: The posted code isn't valid C# - it lacks namespace and class declarations.

Comment: @DaleBurrell Yes, I am. The assemblies are posted in the USING. Everytime I add what it ask, it ask for a new 1. Also, you can add more from .NET to SQL the same way you create a Assembly. Just have the link and it will load as long as your SQL is set to 1 in the sys.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I think this might be a bit to advanced for you as SQL Userdefined Functions in VS DO NOT NEED namespace.  Class declarations are also not the problem. This isn't the whole code as well.